# Pass Args to Child Script From Perl

Tags: perl, arguments, parent-child

I have a perl script in which I'm using as a wrapper. The perl script collects arguments from the user and then calls a child script with arguments as array.

The problem I'm having is that when the child script is executed, all the arguments are in ARGV[1]. Is there some special delimiter I could use? I'd really prefer not to have to loop an array inside the child script; kind of defeats the purpose.

[KSH Script]

```
Your Args
ARG1: foo bar
ARG2:
```

However the result I was expecting is

```
Your Args
ARG1: foo
ARG2: bar
```

I have pushed the arguments into an array and provided the arguments as the array.

[Perl Script]

```
 print "Enter $arg_array[$i]: ";
 my $value = <STDIN>;
 chomp $value;
 if (defined $value) {
     push (@arg_entry, "$value"); #create args array to pass to selectd script

  }
  .... sometime later, in another function ......

  system("$select_script", "@arg_entry");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `system` either you pass a single string, that will be interpreted with a shell (and obeying the separation of arguments by whitespace):

```
system 'command arg1 arg2';
```

Or you use multiple arguments, like you did. In this case the first parameter is the program and each of the following ones is an argument.

```
system 'command', 'arg1', 'arg2';
```

So, since you joined all your arguments by interpolating them in a string (with "@arg_entry") then they were given as one. The solution is simple, just don't interpolate and they will be inserted normally, in the argument list.

```
system 'command', @args;
system($select_script, @arg_entry);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I reached the end of the internet with searching on alternatives to call this.

The first line of the 3rd code block was the answer!

Comment: @JeremyWinslow Glad that it got sorted out. BTW the interpolations of `"$select_script"` and `"$value"` are not needed at all, you can just use the variable directly.

Comment: @JeremyWinslow was it very dark there?